# jQuery Undelegate does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I'm creating a responsive template and I want to remove the listeners on an element when screen is being resized or is smaller than the specified width.
Imagine an menu which when you hover on it's items, it shows you the sub-menus in normal displays but the same menu in mobile devices will show the sub-menus only by tapping or clicking on the items.

I can't make the undelegate work. In resized screen I still have the `mouseover` and `mouseout` event-listeners. I'm not getting any errors in console and I've tried both:

- `.off('mouseover', 'li')`
- `.off('mouseover')`
- `.undelegate('li', 'mouseover')`
- `.undelegate('li')`

and none of them works.

```
var $window = $(window);
    function handleSidenav() {
    $(".nav-list").delegate('li', 'mouseover', function(e) {
        $(this).find("a").addClass('active');
        $(this).find("div.sub-items").toggle();
    }).delegate('li', 'mouseout', function(e) {
        $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).find("div.sub-items").toggle();
    });
}

function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize < 767) {
        smallScreenDelegation();
    } else {
        SmallScreenUndelegation();
    }
}
checkWidth();
handleSidenav();
$window.resize(checkWidth());

function smallScreenDelegation() {
    $(".nav-list").undelegate('li'); //It's not working
    $(".nav-list").undelegate('li'); //It's not working
    $(".nav-list").delegate('li a:first', 'click', function(event) {
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
        }               
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });
}
```

Comment: You do of course realize you've just made a major boo-boo, as you're rebinding the event handlers on each and every browser resize, probably at some point causing something similar to a stack overflow ?

Comment: I've run into this before, and I think it has to do with you adding a class on to the delegate mouseover before that class exists.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder `mouseover` and `mouseout` are often simulated on touch devices when a touch happens.

Comment: @adeneo I'm sure you are right! but I couldn't come with a better solution. Anyhow, how much a browser window may resize?

Comment: @t.niese In `SmallScreenUndelegation()` I don't have any delegation or undelegation, so I thought I can remove it to make my question smaller.

Comment: @nick all of these codes are inside the `document.ready` statement, so I'm binding the `mouseover` and `mouseout` to the element right after the load of DOM.

Comment: Well, the line `$window.resize(checkWidth());` definitely contains a bug.

Comment: `checkWidth` won't be called when the window is resized.

Comment: Ah, I see - it was correct in your first post but then you changed it. Also, shouldn't `handleSideNav()` come before `checkWidth()`?

Comment: @SeanHogan Yeah, you are right but that didn't solve my problem too.

Comment: @SeanHogan I managed to solve my problem by rewriting whole code. I had another bug as 'adeneo' mentioned which I think I've fixed it. Please take a look at my answer and tell me if it's still wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what was wrong with `undelegate` which I couldn't make it work, but I managed to fix my code by using `on` and `off`.

As [adeneo said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266581/jquery-undelegate-does-not-work?noredirect=1#comment23277711_16266581) I was delegating and undelegating on each window resize which was quiet a bug and I think I fixed that but holding the last state on `device` variable.

```
var $window = $(window);
var device;

function desktopSidenav() {
    $(".nav-list > li").off('click');
    $(".nav-list > li").on('mouseover', function(e) {
        $(this).find("a").addClass('active');
        $(this).find("div.sub-items").toggle();
    }).on('mouseout', function(e) {
        $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).find("div.sub-items").toggle();
    });
}

function handheldSidenav() {
    $(".nav-list > li").off('mouseover').off('mouseout');
    $(".nav-list > li").on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(this).find("div.sub-items").is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).find("a:first").addClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $(this).find("a:first").removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
        }               
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
}
```

Now I check the window size before doing anything else an I'll hold the device type in `device` variable. If window is resized, I'm gonna check the device state and do the things based on device type.

```
if ($window.width() > 767) {
    device = 'desktop';
    desktopSidenav();
} else {
    device = 'handheld';
    handheldSidenav();
}
$window.resize(function() {
    if ($window.width() > 767) {
        if (device == 'handheld') {
            device = 'desktop';
            desktopSidenav();
        }
    } else {
        if (device == 'desktop') {
            device = 'handheld';
            handheldSidenav();
        }
    }
});
```

If I use `delegate` and `undelegate` instead of `on` and `off`, the code won't work and I still don't know why, so this cannot be count as a real answer, but I wanted to tell everyone who has a similar problem to use jQuery's `on` and `off` instead on `delegate`.

Comment: It sounds like you are not sure which code paths are really being run in different circumstances. Add lots of `console.log` statements to learn what is really happening. It would be quicker than: guess; fail; guess again; fail again; ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap window in the jQuery object. I'm not sure if you set $window = $(window), but it seems here that $window.width() and $window.resize(checkWidth) are missing parenthesis. I was able to get it working fine once I changed those to $(window). You have to define which event you want to undelegate. I used:

```
 $('.nav-list').undelegate('li', 'mouseover');
```

Open up console and you can see that it works: http://jsbin.com/efonut/6/edit

Also, it's really best to use .on() and off() vs .delegate() and .undelegate(), but at least this works...

Comment: sorry I'm a litte late but I've declared `var $window = $(window);` earlier and thanks for mentioning the missing parenthesis for `$window.resize(checkWidth());` but I'm still unable to make it work.